# Spout not waiting for new message from Kafka

Tags: apache-storm

I am moving Kafka message to JDBC. Currently for the sake of running my code, I am only printing the message on the console. My current Kafka queue is getting printed in console logs but it is not waiting for new Kafka message and the program is stopping without any error. I want my Storm code to run forever and print the any new Kafka message coming.

Comment: Please do *not *resubmit the topology in a while loop. See also the oficial Storm Tutorials! It needs to be submitted just once and then runs until you actively kill it. Please try this first and then report if your program worked.

Comment: When I am not submitting it in while loop, the program is not waiting for new message and the program is getting self killed.

Comment: This is not true. Maybe you have a bug anywhere and the program terminates. But the while loop itself is in the KafkaSpout/bolt, that waits for the tuples. Can you check all logs on all hosts for errors?

Comment: I have taken out my topology from the while loop and now again my code is not waiting for the new message from Kafka. Can you please help me to identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As this is the first time I was using Storm. I made a mistake of using the very old version of Store-Core due to which I was facing this issue. After updating Storm-core to the latest version my issue is resolved.

Thanks @moosehead42 for giving me fair idea that helped me in solving the problem.